# How to get age in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, timestamp

I'm new to the SQL and I want to create a trigger in PostgreSQL that checks if a person is adult from string "personalNumber" which is in format 'yymmdd'. 
My problem is I can't find any way to create a timestamp from the string so I can use it in the age() function.

Here is my code so far. I know I have the age first input variable wrong but I just can't find a way to make it work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_person_adult() RETURNS trigger AS $person$
BEGIN

  IF age(substr(new."personalNumber", 0, 2) + "-" + substr(new."personalNumber", 2, 4) + "-" + substr(new."personalNumber", 4, 6), current_date) > 18 THEN
    new.isadult = TRUE;
   ELSE
    new.isadult := FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
$person$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER person_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON person
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE is_person_adult();
```

Comment: Note that the result you store will be outdated by tomorrow, and storing dependent data violates [second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form). It's better to store the birthday and calculate the age at the time you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `to_timestamp` function to convert this string to a timestamp, and then apply `age` to it. Note that `age` returns an interval, not an integer, so you'd have to check it against an interval of 18 years:

```
IF AGE(TO_TIMESTAMP(new.personalNumber, 'yymmdd')) > INTERVAL '18 years' THEN
    new.isadult := TRUE;
ELSE
    new.isadult := FALSE;
END IF;
```

Note that since `isadult` is a `boolean`, you don't need the if-else construct, and could just assign it directly:

```
new.isadult := 
    (AGE(TO_TIMESTAMP(new.personalNumber, 'yymmdd')) > INTERVAL '18 years');
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea the whole thing could fit in one simple row. :)